`QObject.moveToThread` does not take a slot with it in PySide6
I am troubleshooting a threading application and I noticed the following behaviour: in PySide6, I would like to connect to both slots and non-slot methods, which accoridng to documentation should work. However it does not work as expected. I am not sure if it is a bug or I am doing something incorrectly?

In PySide6, if a QObject is first connected and then moved into a new thread inside a slot, the slots of the QObject will not execute in the new thread when invoked by a signal (with a QueuedConnection), however the methods that are not slots will. If the object is first moved and then connected up, everything is ok.
In PyQt5, the situation is reversed. Methods that are not slots do not follow the QObject to a new thread but slots do. My understanding is that this is correct, since in PyQt5 the slot declaration was obligatory for QueuedConnection to work.

I built a minimal application that illustrates the problem. The buttons are clicked in sequence to move the Dummy object into a new thread and then trying to call do_work method/do_work_slot slot with buttons via different mechanisms and inspecting the thread in which the method is executed.

Clicking the buttons in sequence from top to bottom in PyQt5 gives log:
MainThread:move_to_thread: object thread: Main Thread, execution thread: Main Thread
MainThread:do_work: object thread: new thread, execution thread: Main Thread
MainThread:do_work: object thread: new thread, execution thread: Main Thread
Dummy-1:do_work_slot: object thread: new thread, execution thread: new thread
Dummy-1:do_work_slot: object thread: new thread, execution thread: new thread

whereas in PySide6 it is:
MainThread:move_to_thread: object thread: Main Thread, execution thread: Main Thread
MainThread:do_work: object thread: new thread, execution thread: Main Thread
Dummy-1:do_work: object thread: new thread, execution thread: new thread
MainThread:do_work_slot: object thread: new thread, execution thread: Main Thread
Dummy-1:do_work_slot: object thread: new thread, execution thread: new thread

Note that the thread affinity of the object is correct for both packages.
The behaviour I expected on PySide6 is (I added extra stars for highlight of the relevant bits)
MainThread:move_to_thread: object thread: Main Thread, execution thread: Main Thread
MainThread:do_work: object thread: new thread, execution thread: Main Thread
Dummy-1:do_work: object thread: new thread, execution thread: **new thread**
**Dummy-1**:do_work_slot: object thread: new thread, execution thread: **new thread**
Dummy-1:do_work_slot: object thread: new thread, execution thread: new thread

I attach the application.
import logging
import sys, os
os.environ["QT_API"] = "pyqt5" # ""PySide6"
from qtpy import QtCore, QtWidgets
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(threadName)s:%(name)s: %(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG)

msg_template = "object thread: {thread1}, execution thread: {thread2}"
class Dummy(QtCore.QObject):
    sigMoveToThread = QtCore.Signal()
    sigMoveToMain = QtCore.Signal()
    sigRequestWork = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.sigMoveToThread.connect(self.move_to_thread)
        self.sigMoveToMain.connect(self.move_to_main)
        self.sigRequestWork.connect(self.do_work_slot)

    def do_work(self):
        logging.info(msg_template.format(
            thread1=self.thread().objectName(),
            thread2=QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName()
        ))

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def do_work_slot(self):
        logging.info(msg_template.format(
            thread1=self.thread().objectName(),
            thread2=QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName()
        ))

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def move_to_thread(self):
        logging.info(msg_template.format(
            thread1=self.thread().objectName(),
            thread2=QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName()
        ))
        new_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        new_thread.setObjectName("new thread")
        self.moveToThread(new_thread)
        new_thread.start()
        self.t = new_thread # to avoid garbage collector


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

    QtCore.QThread.currentThread().setObjectName("Main Thread")
    dummy = Dummy()
    # moving to thread at THIS stage as below would result in correct moving
    # of both Slot and non-Slot connection in PySide6
    # thread = QtCore.QThread()
    # dummy.moveToThread(thread)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click (Direct connection, not slot)")
    button.clicked.connect(dummy.do_work, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click (Queued connection, not slot)")
    button.clicked.connect(dummy.do_work, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click (Queued connection, slot)")
    button.clicked.connect(dummy.do_work_slot, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click (sigRequestWork)")
    button.clicked.connect(dummy.sigRequestWork.emit)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Move to thread (move_to_thread slot)")
    button.clicked.connect(dummy.move_to_thread, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Move to thread (sigMoveToThread)")
    button.clicked.connect(dummy.sigMoveToThread.emit, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
    layout.addWidget(button)

    widget.setLayout(layout)
    window.setCentralWidget(widget)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Apparently upgrading from PySide6-6.6.1 to PySide-6.7.1 helped.
I also checked in PyQt6-6.7.1 and it works as expected.
